# Wilcoxon Rank-Sum vs Signed Rank for paired

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I'm working with a dataset that contains paired samples (but some samples are missing their pair) and I want to check for an association between a binary variable and a bunch of numeric variables. Here's what my data looks like:

```
Sample    Cohort    Measure_1    Measure_2    Measure_3    ....
Pt01_pre    A         56.98       698.55      0.7849
Pt01_post   A         46.63       395.42      0.3709
Pt02_pre    A         52.78       248.51      0.7632
Pt03_pre    B         56.44       597.35      0.6845
Pt03_post   B         12.95       448.38      0.4844
```

Note that in this example, sample Pt02 lacks a 'post' pair. Also note that each pair of samples belong to the same cohort. My primary question is **"Does Cohort significantly associate with any of the Measurements?"** If that association is consistently different in "pre" vs "post" samples, I am also interested to know that.

My intention is to write an R script that will loop through each numerical variable to run an appropriate statistical test and report the results but I am having a hard time choosing an appropriate test.

1. One option I am considering is the Wilcoxon Rank-Sum test applied to all samples, to all "pre" samples, and to all "post" samples. My understanding is that its a non-parametric way to compare a numeric variable across two populations and is very similar to the Mann-Whitney u test. I figure that by running it three times I'll be able to see if the association is stronger when looking at all the samples or one of the subsets by just comparing p-values .
2. Another option I am considering is the Wilcoxon Signed-Rank test applied to all pairs of samples (unpaired samples would simply be removed). My understanding is that this test is good for comparing paired-samples and that it will tell me how strong the association is between "pre" and "post" for the numerical variable - but I am not clear on whether there is a way to use it to look at the effect of a second binary variable. If nothing else, I figure I can use the Signed-Rank test to assess which measures show greater measures in the pre vs post

Again, my primary goal is to compare a binary variable against a set of numeric measurements but my data is made up of paired samples. I would very much appreciate knowing:

- if there is anything problematic about my two intended approaches
- how my to intended approaches compare to each other (I'm leaning towards #1)
- if either of my intended approaches is distinctly better than the other
- if there are any other statistical tests that would be better suited for comparing two populations of paired samples.

Comment: I'm confused about your objectives and your proposed solutions.  Wouldn't you want a single model that includes Time (pre/post) and Cohort (A/B) for each Measure?  This might get complicated statistically with having missing data and Subject nested within Cohort, but something like, Measure_1 ~ Cohort + Time + (1|Subject), where Subject is Pt.  Would this address your objective of "Does Cohort significantly associate with any of the Measurements?"